# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: Could not derive key

Tags: java, web-services, webservice-client, httpsurlconnection

I am posting a webservice with parameter sets via HttpsURLConnection.My Jdk version  is 1.8.But I am getting error from webservice.But I couldn't find the solution of the problem.Stacktrace is following as;

```
      javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: Could not derive key
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1903)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1402)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:259)
at sikke.cli.helpers.Helpers.sendPost(Helpers.java:75)
at sikke.cli.helpers.Methods.createAccountAndSave(Methods.java:538)
at sikke.cli.helpers.Methods.createAccountAndSave(Methods.java:503)
at sikke.cli.JSONRPC.Methods(JSONRPC.java:28)
at sikke.cli.EchoPostHandler.handle(EchoPostHandler.java:74)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$DefaultExecutor.execute(ServerImpl.java:158)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Dispatcher.handle(ServerImpl.java:431)
at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Dispatcher.run(ServerImpl.java:396)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My post connection methos as follows;

```
public String sendPost(String path, String urlParameters) throws Exception {
    String server = system.getConf("server");
    String url = server.equals("1") ? "https:....." : "https:....";
    url += path;

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    // con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
    }

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    return response.toString();
}
```

Where am i doing wrong.How can I solve the problem.

Comment: you need to add SSLFactory for handshaking try this https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/11/how-to-setup-custom-sslsocketfactorys-trustmanager-per-each-url-connection.html

Comment: Hi bro thnaks your reply.I tried your solution but the error continues without any changes.

Comment: did you succeed?

Comment: Yes I tried. the problem is that; I've detected a problem with the API certificate.
It gives a read-write error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i fixed it when i changed the sdk.
I downloded java8 from open jdk and the problem was fixed.
Downloded from this link --> https://openjdk.java.net/install/